# Group Entries of a map into list

Tags: dictionary, java-8, java-stream, grouping, entryset

Let's suppose i have a HashMap with some entries:

```
Map hm= new HashMap();
hm.put(1,"ss");
hm.put(2,"ss");
hm.put(3,"bb");
hm.put(4,"cc");
hm.put(5,"ss");
```

i want output like:

```
[{1,ss},{2,ss},{5,ss}]
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I see that you are using raw types (e.g. `Map` without type arguments). Several answers already mention this – you should never use raw types, always specify type arguments, i.e. `Map<Integer, String>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is:

```
List<Map.Entry<Integer,String>> list =
    hm.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You should change the definition of your `Map` to:

```
Map<Integer,String> hm = new HashMap<>();
```

P.S. You didn't specify whether you want all the entries in the output `List`, or just some of them. In the sample output you only included entries having "ss" value. This can be achieved by adding a filter:

```
List<Map.Entry<Integer,String>> list =
    hm.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue().equals("ss")).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println (list);
```

Output:

```
[1=ss, 2=ss, 5=ss]
```

EDIT: You can print that `List` in the desired format as follows:

```
System.out.println (list.stream ().map(e -> "{" + e.getKey() + "," + e.getValue() + "}").collect (Collectors.joining (",", "[", "]")));
```

Output:

```
[{1,ss},{2,ss},{5,ss}]
```

Comment: output is coming like - [1=ss, 2=ss, 3=bb, 4=cc, 5=ss]. My question was if  this statement can be the answer.   [{1,ss},{2,ss},{5,ss}]

Comment: @ShrutiGusain See the second part of my answer, that contains `filter`. That would produce the output `[1=ss, 2=ss, 5=ss]`.

Comment: I want output in the same pattern as shown in my output i.e., entry set inside curly braces. Is this possible?

Comment: @ShrutiGusain what do you want the type of the output List to be? `List<Map.Entry<Integer,String>>` or `List<SomethingElse>`? That would affect my answer.

Comment: The output should be in a pattern  like  -  [ {EntrySet.key , EntrySet.Value } ,  {EntrySet.key , EntrySet.Value } ]

Comment: Yeah, it worked. Thanks. I thought it has something to do with Grouping but it can be done using joining too. Great

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you declare your HashMap like this:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
```

Then after putting the key and the values you can print the whole HashMap it like this:

```
System.out.println("Mappings of HashMap hm1 are : " + hm);
```

If you want to print the value where the key is equal to 1 then:

```
if (hm.containsKey(1)) { 
            String s = hm.get(1); 
            System.out.println("value for key 1 is: " + s); 
        }
```

Comment: The output should be in a pattern like - [ {EntrySet.key , EntrySet.Value } , {EntrySet.key , EntrySet.Value } ] and yeah, sorry I need this to be done using streams